# Get max date from file using Pig latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, apache-pig-grunt

I have a text file with dates and some other columns.
Date column values are of format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'.

From the text file, I would like to get max date or latest date.
(Note: I have seen MAX function only working when GROUP BY in Pig Latin)

Can anyone suggest if there is a way to get that using Pig Latin or any alternative?

Comment: Share us some sample of the input and how do you expect the output to be for the given input

Comment: `Apple|$600|2009-01-14 00:00:00|
Apple|$650|2010-12-16 10:20:20|
Banana|$800|2019-12-14 00:00:00|
Banana|$800|2016-11-11 01:45:03|`


From the above input, I should be able to get the maxdate which is 2019-12-14 00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample dataset,

```
Apple|$600|2009-01-14 00:00:00| 
Apple|$650|2010-12-16 10:20:20| 
Banana|$800|2019-12-14 00:00:00| 
Banana|$800|2016-11-11 01:45:03|
```

The maximum value from the date column can be retrieved using

```
fruits = LOAD 'fruits.txt' using PigStorage('|');
dt = FOREACH fruits GENERATE ToDate($2, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
odt = ORDER dt by $0 DESC;
max = LIMIT odt 1;
dump max;
```